# Excel- Filling missing values based on other values on same row

Tags: excel, missing-data, excel-2016

I need to deal with missing data present in almost every row. Sample of data is as follows:

```
Col1  Col2   Col3      Col4 Col5

10      12      -        14   12
-        8      10       14    -
14       -      -        10   12
```

As you can see that, there is no linear pattern in the data across rows and even if I planned to fill the blanks with mean of previous and next values , there are cases that might not have previous or next value. So please suggest on a way to fill these blanks using Excel.

Comment: What is the logic for filling in those missing values?

Comment: I was hoping to make a smooth curve of the data. Nearest value depending upon the direction of data (increasing or decreasing).

Comment: If the data is a key row dependent, remove a item from a row could meaning remove the entire row.  Is there some key in the rows that you want to keep?

Answer (score 0):

Interpolating smooth curves is a terrible beast, and wildly inaccurate when you have only 3 data points. Your easiest option (and no less valid for these sized data sets) is to just eyeball it and charts can help with this.

Transpose your data and put in an x-series that is just 1 to 5 (or however many data points you have). Then select all of the data and insert a Scatter Plot chart with smooth lines:
[image]

Then try adding values until they look smooth:
[image]

Comment: I wanted to make the use case more clear and hence included only 3 records. However, in real I'm currently looking to impute missing values for close to 15000 records. So I don't think eyeballing could really help me here. Thanks for your inputs though . Much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Curved interpolation is not feasible, but you can do some simple linear interpolation:

Column A: =2*B1-C1
Column B (and C and D): =(A1+C1)/2
Column E: =2*D1-C1

To handle cells next to each other being blank, first turn on iterative calculations to allow circular references from File > Options > Formulas:
[image]
After running through several iterations, the values will quickly stabilize to create a linear average.

To enter formulas in all blank cells in columns B to D in one go:
1. Select columns B:D
2. Ctrl-G (Goto) > Special > Blanks
3. Type the formula relevant for that active cell with relative references
4. Press Ctrl-Enter to save it to all blank cells

This doesn't handle 2 blank cells next to each other at the start or end though.